SAMPLE BY and UNION precedence on QuestDB
I have two tables which store candlestick data.  One is real-time, another is backfilled from history which only contain 1 minute candlesticks. I have this working query
SELECT timestamp, first(open) as open, max(high) as high, min(low) as low, last(close) as close, sum(volume) as volume 
FROM "coinbase-candlesticks" 
WHERE symbol = 'BTC/USD'
SAMPLE BY 5m 
UNION
SELECT timestamp, first(open) as open, max(high) as high, min(low) as low, last(close) as close, sum(volume) as volume 
FROM "coinbase-historical" 
WHERE symbol = 'BTC/USD'
SAMPLE BY 5m 
ORDER BY timestamp ASC
LIMIT 100000;

Here's my question, can I use sample and union in the same query, does the UNION portion distinct the query before applying sample?  I just want to make sure it does that so there isn't any overlap and the sample aggregation works properly.

If we run EXPLAIN on that query, we will see the UNION happens after the sample (in this case, the engine compiles the sample to a group by clause).
Therefore, we would need to subquery the union first, then sample second to make sure no overlap exists.
WITH candlestickQuery AS 
(
  SELECT timestamp, open, high, low, close, volume
  FROM "coinbase-candlesticks" 
  WHERE timeframe = 1 and symbol = 'BTC/USD'
  UNION
  SELECT timestamp, open, high, low, close, volume
  FROM "coinbase-historical" 
  WHERE timeframe = 1 and symbol = 'BTC/USD'
  ORDER BY timestamp ASC
) 
SELECT timestamp, first(open) as open, max(high) as high, min(low) as low, last(close) as close, sum(volume) as volume 
FROM candlestickQuery
SAMPLE BY 5m 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC;

